# Delete lines which contain a number smaller/larger than a user specified value

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I need to delete lines in a large file which contain a value larger than a user specified number(see picture). For example I'd like to get rid of lines with values larger than 5e-48 (x>5e-48), i. e. lines with 7e-46, 7e-40, 1e-36,.... should be deleted.

Can sed, grep, awk or any other command do that?

Thank you

Markus

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Just copy the text and paste it into your question. That way we can easily copy it into a file and play with it in order to test our answers.

Answer (score 5):

With awk:

```
awk '$3 <= 5e-48' filename
```

This selects only those lines whose third field is smaller than 5e-48.

If fields can contain spaces (since the data appears to be tab-separated) use

```
awk -F '\t' '$3 <= 5e-48' filename
```

This sets the field separator to `\t`, so lines are split at tabs rather than any whitespace. It does not appear to be necessary with the shown input data, but it is good practice to be defensive about these things (thanks to @tripleee for pointing this out).

Comment: If the file is tab-delimited, add `-F '\t'`

Comment: What makes anyone think his fields are separated by tabs?

Comment: The arrows in the screenshot, and that they line up their respective next characters at what appear to be four-character intervals.

Comment: Thanks very much for solving my problem!

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, for example, the solution can be

```
perl -ane'print unless$F[2]>5e-48'
```